# Don't show like button in case facebook is blocked

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to not show facebook's like button in case facebook is blocked or facebook cannot be accessed.

If facebook is blocked, I see the error displayed within the area where like button is supposed to be shown, which looks pretty bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make simple http call to the facebook and depending on response (ok, 403,404) - decide show or not the badge.

Comment: I was looking for some error handling within the xfbml, it seems there is nothing as such.

Answer (score 2):

check if you get an error accessing the website:

```
$url = 'http://www.facebook.com';
list($status) = get_headers($url);
if (strpos($status, '404') !== FALSE) {
   // URL is not available
} else {
    // URL is available
}
```